# Syntax of Wifi for NFC

Tags: wifi, nfc

What is syntax for wifi to write to an `NFC` tag with which WIFI of android phone should be activated? I have already used `"wifi://[ssid]/[wpa]/[pwd]"`, but it is not working. Can anyone help?